# ubuntu as multi port router

Tags: networking, iptables, router

If I have an 4 (or more) ethernet port linux box, How to setup it as router to handle 4 class c subnet ? for example, eth0 => 192.168.1.0/24, eth1 => 192.168.2.0/24, eth2 => 192.168.3.0/24, eth3 => 192.168.4.0/24, each client machine with in those 4 subnets can talk to each other.

Any suggest script ?

Answer (score 2):

Per your interfaces settings, you need to let the kernel do Network Address Translation to route packets across these subnets. Try this first:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j SNAT --to 192.168.2.1
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.1
```

Where `192.168.2.1` is the IP address of eth1 and the default gateway for subnet `192.168.2.0/24`, `192.168.1.1` alike.

And make sure you have `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. And run `sysctl -p` to make that change in effect.

Comment: Please comment if that works or not. I do not have machines to test right now at work.

Comment: Bad argument '192.168.2.1'
Bad argument '192.168.1.1'
By the way, I am using Ubuntu Server 11.10 i386
3.0.0-17-generic-pae #30-Uuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 17:53:35 UTC...

Comment: ok, I am change the -j SNAT 192.168.2.1 ==> j- SNAT --to 192.168.2.1, It's accept now.

Comment: Sorry, I now update my post. You can test with only one iptables rule first.

Comment: Thanks your help. It's won't work if only with POSTROUTING/SNAT, But after add PREROUTING/DNAT, It's work now......  :)

Comment: What are your DNAT rule? can you post all your rules if everything is working?

Comment: I am add</ BR>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.1</ BR>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1</ BR>
Now can ping each other, but can't access other service, ex: http. I am stilling try to working out.

Comment: I am add
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.1, and
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1</ BR>
Now can ping each other, but can't access other service, ex: http. From 192.168.1.a can access 192.168.1.b's http, but can't access 192.168.2.a's http, vice versa, I am stilling try to working out.

Comment: You DNAT to the gateway IP, that's why you cannot access the services of the subnets. DNAT is in fact automatically done in the reverse direction of SNAT. There are more to know and to do to solve your problem.

Comment: if only SNAT, I can't ping between subnet.  >_<

Comment: I am going crazy. If clear all rule (none of DNAT/SNAT). I can access service (http) cross subnet. ex: http://192.168.1.x from 192.168.2.x, http://192.168.2.x from 192.168.1.x. But can't ping any machine cross subnet. ex: ping 192.168.1.x from 192.168.2.x, ping 192.168.2.x from 192.168.1.x. But after add DNAT/SNAT rule, I can ping cross subnet, but the service won't work. How should I do to allow both ping and service .... >_<!!